# Recreate database before each test class with Liquibase

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing, liquibase

I am using Spring Boot with JUnit5 with [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) during my integration testing. I create my database with Liquibase during the startup. I am using a single instance of my database and I wouldn't like to restart the whole container. But I would like to drop all database objects and recreate the database by Liquibase changelog before every test class.

I found a few possibilities but these are very painful to use.

- I can write the scripts manually which I wouldn't like because I have to update them every time.
- I know, I can restart the database container but it would make testing so long.
- Also @DirtiesContext takes too much time.

Is there a solution telling Liquibase to drop everything and then rerun the changelog? (Or there is no solution for this use case because it is a bad idea?)

Comment: It is not a bad idea, why not? But it could take a lot of time too, depends on the quantity of changesets. From my own experience, it took ~40 minutes for applying 8k changesets to oracle database on a bare metal server. So, it seems better to leave schema and cut out only the state. It should be much more faster, then full recreation of the database schema.

Comment: How should I drop the state without dropping the schema? Does it mean I have to write the queries for the job?

Comment: For example, just call truncate table for all the tables in your database. If you don't want to manually update this script for new tables, just write procedure that select all table name from database into the cursor and then iterate over the cursor to call truncate on each table. This approach will not revert some particular objects, as sequences (in oracle), but it will not affect your test scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad idea, keeping in mind that it could take time to run depending on the number of changesets. A better option is to leave the schema and only cut the state, which will be much faster.

Example:
call truncate table for all the tables in your database. You can manually write a script for new tables, or write a procedure that selects all table names from the database into the cursor. Then iterate over the cursor to call truncate on each table. This will not affect your test scenarios, but it also will not revert some particular objects, such as sequences in Oracle.

Reference:

- Comments from @Gleb Yan above
- [Liquibase Documentation: Tools & Integrations: Spring Boot](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/springboot/home.html?Highlight=spring%20boot)